# Using JSON DATA Without OPENJSON And Search by Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, json-query

```
[
    {
        "Level"       : "S1",
        "Major"       : "Teknik Informatika"
    },
    {
        "Level"       : "SMA",
        "Major"       : "IPA"
    },
    {
        "Level"       : "SMP",
        "Major"       : "Umum"
    },
    {
        "Level"       : "SD",
        "Major"       : "Umum"
  }
]
```

```
iD  | UserID  | Education
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | B000-1  | [{"Level":"S1","Major":"TI"},{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}]
2   | B000-2  | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPS"},{"Level":"SD","Major":"Umum"}]
3   | B000-3  | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}]
4   | B000-4  | [{"Level":"SD","Major":"Umum"}]
```

Jika setiap kolom table `Education` kurang lebih berisi seperti object diatas, bagaimana saya mencari data `Education[Level]='SMA'` tanpa menggunakan OPENJSON, karena saya menggunakan sql server 2012

Translate :
If every column in `Education` table contains objects like above, how can I find `Education[Level]='SMA'` without using `OPENJSON`, because I am using SQL Server 2012

```
iD  | UserID  | Education
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | B000-1  | [{"Level":"S1","Major":"TI"},{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}]
2   | B000-2  | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPS"},{"Level":"SD","Major":"Umum"}]
3   | B000-3  | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}]
```

Comment: What about brute-force `LIKE`? `WHERE Education LIKE '"Level":"SMA"`... Will it work with your data type for `Education` column?

Comment: If you cannot use `LIKE` directly, you can `CAST` the column to `varchar`.

Comment: type `nvarchar(MAX)`

Comment: Then do try `LIKE` approach

Answer (score 0):

A quick search lead me to [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Here the auther shows how 'older' versions of SQL Server can read/write JSON objects/strings. The solution needs to be tailored to your needs, as your JSON structure is different, but it is possible.

Or you can brute force `like` .. like [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) suggested above

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following solution.

We are converting JSON data into attributes based XML. For example, for the first row it will be like follows:

```
<root>
    <r Level="S1" Major="TI"/>
    <r Level="NotSMA" Major="IPA"/>
</root>
```

After that XQuery method `.exist()` is used to search for the @Level parameter.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Education NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tbl (Education) VALUES
(N'[{"Level":"S1","Major":"TI"},{"Level":"NotSMA","Major":"IPA"}]'),
(N'[{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPS"},{"Level":"SD","Major":"Umum"}]'),
(N'[{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(4) = '},{"'
    , @Level VARCHAR(20) = 'SMA';

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r ' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Education, '":', '=')
        , ',"', SPACE(1))
        , '}]', '')
        , '[{"', ''), @separator, '/><r ') + 
        '/></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
WHERE c.exist('/root/r[@Level=sql:variable("@Level")]') = 1;
```

**Output**

| ID | Education |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPS"},{"Level":"SD","Major":"Umum"}] |
| 3 | [{"Level":"SMA","Major":"IPA"}] |